# OpenCPU API - Console output

Tags: r, opencpu

Using the current version of OpenCPU, I would like to raise exceptions to the front end based on the output of OpenCPU API /console URL however this is only displaying the Errors but no Warnings which can be helpful at times. For example I have some script which I am forcing to error out for testing purposes and the R console outputs Error as well as a Warning. However through the API /console URL in the browser I only see the Error and no Warnings. Is this by design or is there a way to push both Errors and Warnings?